# Parallelizing a gensim KeyedVectors model in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, gensim, word2vec

I have a a gensim Word2Vec KeyedVectors model. For speed purposes, I would like to parallelize my program so that it can run in a Spark environment. However, as far as I am aware Spark's RDDs only work on collections and iterables. I don't think I could actually see a performance boost by simply putting the KeyedVectors model into a RDD.

I have explored storing the model as a broadcast variable, but it is far too large. Partitioning (using an RDD) looks like the best option.

If I wanted to boost my program's performance by converting the model to a parallel collection in Spark, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540970/how-to-load-a-file-in-each-executor-once?noredirect=1#comment96562437_54540970