# How to load a file in each executor once?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, fasttext

I define  the following code in order to load a pretrained embedding model:

```
import gensim

from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText as FT_gensim
import numpy as np

class Loader(object):
    cache = {}
    emb_dic = {}
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, filename):
        print("|-------------------------------------|")
        print ("Welcome to Loader class in python")
        print("|-------------------------------------|")
        self.fn = filename

    @property
    def fasttext(self):
        if Loader.count == 1:
                print("already loaded")
        if self.fn not in Loader.cache:
            Loader.cache[self.fn] =  FT_gensim.load_fasttext_format(self.fn)
            Loader.count = Loader.count + 1
        return Loader.cache[self.fn]


    def map(self, word):
        if word not in self.fasttext:
            Loader.emb_dic[word] = np.random.uniform(low = 0.0, high = 1.0, size = 300)
            return Loader.emb_dic[word]
        return self.fasttext[word]
```

i call this class like :

```
inputRaw = sc.textFile(inputFile, 3).map(lambda line: (line.split("\t")[0], line.split("\t")[1])).map(Loader(modelpath).map)
```

1. Im confusing on How many times the modelpath file will be loaded? I want to be one time loaded per executor and used by all of its cores. My answer for this question is the modelpath will be loades 3 times (=number of partition.). If my answer is right, the disadvantage of such modeling is related to size of file modelpath. Suppose this file is 10 gb and suppose i have 200 partitions. Thus in this case we will need 10*200gb = 2000 with is huge (This solution can only work with low number of partitions.)

Suppose i have an 
`rdd =(id, sentence) =[(id1, u'patina californian'), (id2, u'virgil american'), (id3', u'frensh'), (id4, u'american')]`

and i want to sumup the embedding word vectors for each sentence:

```
def test(document):
    print("document is = {}".format(document))
    documentWords = document.split(" ")
    features = np.zeros(300)
    for word in documentWords:
        features = np.add(features, Loader(modelpath).fasttext[word])
    return features

def calltest(inputRawSource):

    my_rdd = inputRawSource.map(lambda line: (line[0], test(line[1]))).cache()
    return my_rdd
```

In this case how many times the modelpath file will be loaded? Note that i set `spark.executor.instances" to 3`

Comment: Search for Broadcast variables, extenal caching wrt Spark etc

Comment: brodcast a very big file of 10gb is not working

Comment: If the file is small you can Broadcast, if the file is large, you partition it and execute a join. There is no way you can keep all that in memory, there is no magic bullet in my opinion

Comment: Can you try marking the field a 'Transient Lazy' which will not be serialized and each executor should be creating it only once the first time it tries to access.  https://nathankleyn.com/2017/12/29/using-transient-and-lazy-vals-to-avoid-spark-serialisation-issues/

Comment: @skjagini how can make Tranient lasy in pyspark?

Comment: @skjagini i think the way i defined the Loader class is the same as Transient Lazy, no?

Comment: @jaceklaskowski can you please give me your advice to solve this issue

Comment: @howie, can you please help in solving this issue

Comment: I don't think this will work and not efficient . when you call Loader(modelpath).map which means sent all data from spark to python. I will try to use spark dataframe model + UDF . You can put write your Loader in UTF way. And let spark handle your data distribution.

Comment: @howie can you please be more specific?if you want we can move the discussion to the chat

Comment: @bib you can see this first
https://changhsinlee.com/pyspark-udf/

Comment: @howie I think you mean in the same manner as https://forums.databricks.com/questions/11374/pyspark-apply-function-using-large-object.html?childToView=16877#comment-16877 but it is looks like is not working. Im stuck from one month on this issue

Comment: ok~ Now I undertand your problem is you use python's model , and the model is too large. I wander can you use model file into spark dataframe to cacluate without load into gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format

Comment: Is this similary to your question ? https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-a-python-model-more-efficiently-over-spark-497fc03e0a8d

Comment: @howie i dont know exactly. I want to compute the document vector bu summing up the vector of each word in this document (see plz the function test). The word vector s come from an embedding model (wiki.en.bin). My problem come on how to load the wiki.en.bin in each executor, i tried all the way as the link i sent and i get the exceptions.

Comment: I know your problem, and I don't know how to solve it by your way, such as loading total model data into memory (Loader.cache[self.fn] =  FT_gensim.load_fasttext_format(self.fn)). I suggest you load model data into dataframe, and try to do whatever you want to do by this way.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the number of partitions is set to the total number of cores on all the executer nodes in the Spark cluster. Suppose you are processing 10 GB on a Spark cluster (or supercomputing executor) that contains a total of 200 CPU cores, that means Spark might use 200 partitions, by default, to process your data.

Also, to make all your CPU cores work per each executer this can be solved in python (using 100% of all cores with the multiprocessing module).