# How broadcast a huge rdd in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I print out the first element of my rdd as following:

```
print("input = {}".format(input.take(1)[0]))
```

I get a result as :    `(u'motor', [0.001,..., 0.9])`

The type of `[0.001,..., 0.9]` is a list.

The number of elements in the input rdd equal to `53304100`

My problem comes when i want to broadcast the input RDD as following:

```
brod = sc.broadcast(input.collect())
```

The generated exception is the following (I show just the first piece of the exeception):

```
    WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 56.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 176, 172.16.140.144, executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 229, in main
    process()
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 224, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 372, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'document'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RDD is too large, the application might run into a OutOfMemory error,which cause by the collect method pull all the data the driver's memory which usually isn't large enough.

So you can try to incease your driver's memory by

```
pyspark --driver-memory 4g
```

Comment: you mean spark-submit --driver-memory 4g?

Comment: I augment the driver memory and i get a new exception. plz see my modified post

Comment: I think you should try to analyze from spark exector UI , such as (https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-webui.html). It has more information than just error log. Can you paste it ?
I guess you rdd is still too large, maybe you can try to increase the number of partitions to 100 [rdd.repartition(100)] to distribute the data processing across the node and keep the shuffle data below 2 GB. Beside, broadcast is only good for small dataset. You may also try to remove boradcast.

Comment: i run again the code  (severak times).The old excpetion is not appearing when i increase the the number of partition to be 128 (2*32*2).  I update the post to show the new one. by the way can you help if you an idea please on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540970/how-to-load-a-file-in-each-executor-once?noredirect=1#comment95915869_54540970