# how to load a file to each worker?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Im looking a way to distribute a huge file  (8gb, i.e. word2vec pretrained embedding) to be available on each worker.

I fact I have a program to compute the embedding of each document as the sum of its words vectors. Each word has a vector.

There is anyway to download this file per worker?

It is excatly the same as :[How to load a file in each executor once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540970/how-to-load-a-file-in-each-executor-once)
Regards

Comment: Hi! To distribute your file across cluster machines, you could use `sc.paralellize()` method. So, let spark take care of where partitions are located.

Comment: @IgorUchôa paralellize partition the file into several parts and distributes these parts accross the works. I need the entirely file to be in every worker

Comment: If you need to copy files to all cluster machines, you could use `--files` option on spark-submit/pyspark/spark-shell commands. It help you?

Comment: Otherwise, you need to put this file in a distributed file system like HDFS, S3, ADLS, etc.

Comment: @IgorUchôa it makes sense. Suppose in each machine i have 6 workers. Does that mean we will have one copy per workers (i.e. 6 copies) or just on copy and the 6 workers can access this file?

Comment: According with ‘pyspark —help’: --files FILES: Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working directory of each executor. I think that Spark don’t know if executors are in same machine or not. So, even they are located on same node, each executor will have your own working directory and your file will be put in there.